# Intrinsics - cant find <ia64intrin.h> but have <ia32intrin.h>?

Tags: c++, c, intel, intrinsics

Whilst looking at the Intel Intrinsics pdf (to try and work out which headers need to be included) I can see that there is `<ia64intrin.h>` header. However, I only seem to have `<ia32intrin.h>` available.

What do I need to do to setup the ability to use **all** Intel intrinsics features? I have the Intel C/C++ compiler....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do try to focus on the intrinsics that are supported by the specific processor you want to target.  That is pretty unlikely to be an Itanium these days.  So unusual that it isn't included anymore, the Itanium compiler is a separate download.

Comment: Ah I do apologise- I didn't realise the "64" was referring to the Itanium 64 bit instruction set. However, isnt that a little misleading because the non-Itanium processors arent 32 bit (and I assume the relevant intrinsics header file for them is ia32intrin.h)?

Comment: @user997112: "ia" stands for Intel Architecture. Intel's 64 bit architecture indeed is Itanium, and Intel's 32 bit architecture is basically the 80386 with some optional extra's (MMX/SSE). The x86-64 architecture is an AMD design (Athlon 64).